# Finding out which client is making the API call : Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Currently I have a server implementation using the google app engine and the server API is being used across an iPhone, Android and Web client.

Is there any native function available on google app engine which can determine which client type (iphone/android/web) is making the API call?

I know that one way of finding out this information is by passing a key from the clients while making the API call identifying itself as the type of client that it is. But I would like to avoid this implementation across 3 clients.

Attached here is a server log which is originating from an Android client.

```
"GET /api/getAllFeeds?id=xxxx HTTP/1.1" 200 789 - "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; GT-I9300 Build/JRO03C)" "mytestapp.appspot.com" ms=10923 cpu_ms=6629 cpm_usd=0.000088 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c22d1aab5f2fc54eb72f57774552188"
```

So essentially the server seems to know the originating caller type. But I am not sure how to retrieve it from the code.

Thanks for your help 
Rajat

Comment: Using user agent you can identify the web client.

String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");

Answer (score 1):

The caller type is embedded in the header of the HTTP request, under the field `User-Agent`. If your handler use the basic HttpServletRequest class, you could obtain an enumeration of the values on this field by invoking the `getHeaders( "User-Agent" )` method.

If you are using Jersey for your handlers, you could implement a [ContainerRequestFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.2-ea/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) that could intercept the request as a ContainerRequest, and you could invoke the `getRequestHeaders()` to get the headers.

Note that there could be several values contained for a single request field. Think of the headers as a multivalued map.